RedirectResponse не работает в FastAPI
Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Login"　меня перенаправляло на другую страницу, желательно на страницу пользователя, но меня вообще никуда не перенаправляет. Хотя в /docs все работает, html страница возвращается. В чем может быть проблема? Уже перепробовал разные варианты status_code.

main.py

@app.post('/login')
async def get_cust(email_login: str = Form(...), password_login: str = Form(...)):
email_statement = select(Customer).where(Customer.email == email_login)
email_result = session.exec(email_statement).first()

password_statement = select(Customer).where(Customer.password == password_login)
password_result = session.exec(password_statement).first()

if email_result != None and email_result.id == password_result.id:
    return RedirectResponse(url='/', status_code=303)


login.html

<form style="width:300px; margin-top:100px;" class="mx-1 mx-md-4">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                    <input type="email" id="email_login" name="email_login" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                    <input type="password" id="password_login" name="password_login" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style='justify-content:space-around;' class="d-flex mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">

                <input type='submit' data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>



Разобрался

Нужно было в форме написать method="post"
<form style="width:300px; margin-top:100px;" class="mx-1 mx-md-4" method="post">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                    <input type="email" id="email_login" name="email_login" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                    <input type="password" id="password_login" name="password_login" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style='justify-content:space-around;' class="d-flex mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">

                <input type='submit' data-mdb-button-init data-mdb-ripple-init class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>

